# SQL Developer Tool Log Window

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

When export data in SQL Developer I get an extra pop up window that says "TOOL START" Export TOOL AT Date and Time. It does this for every export with a new window.

[image]

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: I just experienced that for the first time today with SQLDev 18.3. It's probably a bug/development artifact that shouldn't have gone to production.  You should probably log a service request with Oracle or at least ask about the issue on the Oracle SQL Developer forum: https://community.oracle.com/community/groundbreakers/database/developer-tools/sql_developer/overview

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug.

For 18.4 you'll see complete export and other utilities information in the log panel.

[image]

It will show start time, number of records, stop time, and a link to the generated file.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this bug fix in your Jan 16th newsletter.